# Ordering custom posts by meta field date

Tags: meta-query, date

I've tried every combination of examples here on the boards and nothing seems to get me what I need. I have an events post type with multiple fields in a custom meta box, one of which is a date field that saves in the form yyyymmdd. I need to query only the events that occur today and in the future, and sort in ASC order by date field. This will be used in a custom post type archive page.

Metabox function:

```
function events_metabox() {
global $post;
$typename = 'events';

$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $typename, true);

$date = ( !empty( $meta['date'] ) ) ? $meta['date'] : '';
$start = ( !empty( $meta['start'] ) ) ? $meta['start'] : '';
$end = ( !empty( $meta['end'] ) ) ? $meta['end'] : '';
$location = ( !empty( $meta['location'] ) ) ? $meta['location'] : '';
$form = ( !empty( $meta['form'] ) ) ? $meta['form'] : '';

wp_nonce_field( $typename, $typename . "-nonce" );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#events_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yymmdd'
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="field">
    <label for="<?php echo $typename; ?>_address">Location:</label>
    <textarea id="<?php echo $typename; ?>_address" name="<?php echo $typename; ?>[location]" class="widefat"><?php echo $location; ?></textarea>
    <em class="field-summary summary">Event location.</em>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="<?php echo $typename; ?>_phone">Event Date:</label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $typename; ?>_date" name="<?php echo $typename; ?>[date]" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
    <em class="field-summary summary">Event date.</em>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="<?php echo $typename; ?>_email">Start Time:</label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $typename; ?>_start" name="<?php echo $typename; ?>[start]" value="<?php echo $start; ?>" />
    <em class="field-summary summary">Start time of event.</em>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="<?php echo $typename; ?>_email">End Time:</label>
    <textarea id="<?php echo $typename; ?>_end" name="<?php echo $typename; ?>[end]"><?php echo $end; ?></textarea>
    <em class="field-summary summary">End time of event.</em>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="<?php echo $typename; ?>_form">Web Form:</label>
    <textarea id="<?php echo $typename; ?>_form" name="<?php echo $typename; ?>[form]" class="widefat"><?php echo $form; ?></textarea>
    <em class="field-summary summary">Web Form.</em>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Function saving the custom meta fields:

```
function events_save_meta($post_id, $post) {
$typename = 'events';
$id = $post->ID;    

if(!isset($_POST[$typename])){
    return $id;
}

$meta = $_POST[$typename];

if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$typename . "-nonce"], $typename)) return $id;

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $id;

if( $typename != $_POST['post_type'] )
    return $id;

update_post_meta($id, $typename, $meta);
}
```

Post Query:

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type'   => 'events',
 'meta_key' => 'date',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
     'key' => 'date',
     'value' => date('Ymd'),
     'compare' => '>=',
     'type' => 'NUMERIC'
  )
 )
);

$events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What have you tried to order the posts by this meta value? If you're 100% sure that your meta_key is saving the date in a `YYYYMMDD` format, then the meta_query should be fairly simple and we would need to see that.

Comment: What Howdy_McGee said was right. Have you tried using custom field query from the codex? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: I'd guess you need to switch the `type` to `numeric`. You can't do `>=` comparisons on strings.

Comment: @helgatheviking, changing the type to NUMERIC still yields no results.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, looking in the DB the post meta_key='events' and an example meta_value=a:5:{s:8:"location";s:6:"Online";s:4:"date";s:8:"20140501";s:5:"start";s:8:"10:00 am";s:3:"end";s:8:"11:00 am";s:4:"form";s:0:"";}

Comment: in your **Post Query** remove `meta-value` that doesn't belong in the query. I'm also a little confused because in the above code you use `event_date` and `date` as meta keys. According to your DB Post Meta it is 'date' unless you have 'event_date' elsewhere. Maybe also replace 'event_date' with 'date'.

Comment: you can't store the date in an array under a single key if you want to query on it. the date has to be stored under its own key.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, yes that was my mistake copying something from another post I was looking at. I have corrected the code per your suggestions but still have the same result. I guess I'll have to date to its own key.

Answer (score 1):

You are not querying/saving the correct `meta_key`. For example, looking at your code, you pass `$typename` variable to `update_post_meta()` as `meta_key` and  `$typename = 'events'`. But later in the query you are querying for `meta_key = date`. Also, you pass `$meta` as `meta_value` and in your actual code `$meta` is an array containing multiple values (location, date, start, etc).

```
 $typename = 'events';
 //$_POST[$typename] is actually an array
 $meta = $_POST[$typename];
 ......
 .....
 update_post_meta($id, $typename, $meta);
```

If you don't touch the HTML of the meta box, you have to change the saving code and the query. For example:

```
add_action('save_post', 'events_save_meta');
function events_save_meta($post_id) {

    $typename = 'events';

    if ( isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'events' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            //You may need to change 'edit_post' for the correct capability set when register 'events' post type
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                 return;
            }
    }

    if( !isset( $_POST[$typename . "-nonce"] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$typename . "-nonce"], $typename) ) {
            return;
    }

    if( isset($_POST[$typename]['date']) ) {
         update_post_meta($post_id, 'date', $_POST[$typename]['date']);
    } else {
         delete_post_meta($post_id, 'date');
    }

 }
```

Now you have a meta field with `meta_key = 'date'` and you can query for this `meta_key`:

```
 $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'events',
      'meta_key' => 'date',
      'meta_value' => current_time('Ymd'),
      'meta_compare' => '>=',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'ASC'
      );

 $events_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```